# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification not called

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I use the following code in the viewDidLoad function of my RootViewController.
In the AppDelegate the ApplicationDidBecomeActive function is called, but the RVC seems not to become the notification, because the function someMethod is not called.
Anybody an idea what the problem is?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                         name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

....

-(void)someMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"OK");
}
```

Comment: have you set a breakpoint to test whether the addObserver: method is really called ?

Comment: Not sure but i would guess it's too late to add a observer for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` in `viewDidLoad` if you expect it to be called at application start. Or is this after starting the application, background it and activate it again? do you remove the observer in `viewDidUnload? etc?

Comment: @luyuan: Yes, I did. The function is not called.

Comment: @MattiasWadman: Yes, I like to use it on getting active from the background. No, I do not remove the observer on viewDidUnload.

Comment: show us more code about where you have call this method

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that in a single view controller app, viewDidLoad is not called until AFTER UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is posted. Therefore, you are registering for the notification after it occurs the first time. Subsequent activations should be caught, such as if you switch apps and come back, but you will miss the first one.

Comment: This is indeed the issue for me, but how can I catch the first UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add an observer for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` that will also be triggered on the first launch, you should add the observer in the function

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

of your app delegate, like so:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                        addObserver:self.window.rootViewController
                           selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                               name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                             object:nil];`

(after setting the root view controller).

This works because didFinishWithLaunching is called before didBecomeActive in the appDelegate on the initial launch of the app.